# Debugging PHP in VSCode stops on breakpoint but doesn't work from there

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, xdebug

I had PHP XDebug configured and working in my WordPress/PHP project. It was working fine, I was able to debug my code, run line by line, watch variables etc.

But suddenly it stopped working. I can start the debugger, it stops on a breakpoint correctly, but from this point nothing works, "Step Over", "Step Through" and event "Continue" commands have no effects. I've tried clicking the buttons and using the keyboard but nothing happens. When I click "Stop", it stops the debugger, but I get the message "Socket not writable". I have another WordPress project which is working fine.

I'm using XAMPP on windows to host my site.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post which may help if related: [XDebug stopped working in PHPStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888326/xdebug-stopped-working-in-phpstorm)

Have you tried xdebug connecting through a different port?

It may be worth posting your debug settings and php.ini xdebug related config if this doesn't help.